# How can ActivatedRoute be injected via Angular DI if it's an Interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

According to Angular's docs on [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute), it is an interface. How then am I able to inject it into a component constructor like so:

```
constructor (private route : ActivatedRoute) {
  console.log(route)
}
```

and get an instance? Especially since Typescript interfaces aren't supposed to exist after build-time!?

Comment: Most probably because the documentation is lying, and ActivatedRoute is in fact a class: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cf0968f98e844043a0f6c2548201f3c0dfd329a7/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L107

Comment: liars!!!!!!!!!!